# How do I change text selection handle color for iOS in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the following theme code:

```
ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
  accentColor: Colors.green,
  textSelectionColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.5),
  textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.green,
);
```

And that works for android, but for iOS it is not changing the color of the text selection handle color to green (it is still the default blue).  How can I change that color for iOS?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to change the color using Themes.  You need to set cupertinoOverrideTheme like this

```
CupertinoThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.green,
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I really wonder why I have to set CupertinoThemeData when I don't use Cupertino widgets. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43887).

It would appear that `TextField` on iOS ignores the `MaterialTheme` values for this.

Another piece of information which suggests that this is not possible in iOS is looking at the [CupertinoThemeData documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoThemeData-class.html), which clearly does not consider a `textSelectionHandleColor`.